# How to add Twitter Maven Repo into my pom file

Tags: maven, twitter

I wanna use some libraries from Twitter Maven Repo http://maven.twttr.com/ , how do I define my pom file? I do the configuration like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>twitter-twttr</id>
        <url>http://maven.twttr.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

It is useless!!! I also find that there is no index file at http://maven.twttr.com/.index like other repository. So how to add the Twitter Repo???

Answer (score 1):

That is how you define a Maven repository in your pom.xml file. Why do you think it is useless? Did you add a dependency as well?

Comment: I got the point, when I use the Maven in command line, it works. However, I use Netbeans(v7.2.1) which has its built-in Maven(v3.04), I wanna add the twitter-twttr repository to this IDE, so I can make use of the autocomplete tip of the IDE when I process dependency. I find that, Netbeans uses the remote url http://maven.twttr.com/.index/ to get the index of the repository, but it finds nothing, any ideas?

Comment: Adding the above pom entry works for me on command line and in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter uses maven 3.1 repository format, 3.0.x version of maven won't work. So for it to work in Netbeans you just have to switch to external maven of the latest version in the Netbeans Maven config.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter, the code in that repo is horribly out of date.  I think the right answer is just to build locally.

-- Patrick